# Running a powershell script from Excel with space in path

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I found a couple of answers here which break at the space between Powershell and scripts.

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim scriptlocation As String
    scriptlocation = "C:\REDACTED\Powershell Scripts\ConmonInfoFinder-V7.ps1"

    Dim x As Variant
    x = Shell("""POWERSHELL.exe"" ""C:\REDACTED\Powershell Scripts\ConmonInfoFinder-V7.ps1""", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Or

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim scriptlocation As String
    scriptlocation = "C:\REDACTED\Powershell Scripts\Powershell Scripts\ConmonInfoFinder-V7.ps1"

    strCommand = "Powershell -File" & scriptlocation
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)
End Sub
```

Both of these open Powershell but they won't run the script. The first one dies at the space in between Powershell Scripts and the second one flashes the windows with no error, but isn't running the script.

EDIT: I made some changes.

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim scriptlocation As String
    scriptlocation = "C:\REDACTED\Powershell Scripts\trial.ps1"

    strCommand = "Powershell -NoExit -File """ & scriptlocation & """"
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)
```

The window still flashes up and then goes away.  I made a sample script of just Hello World to make sure it wasn't anything weird in my script and I have the same result.

EDIT:

It is now fixed.

```vb
Sub Test2()
    Dim scriptlocation As String
    scriptlocation = "C:\REDACTED\Powershell Scripts\ConmonInfoFinder-V7.ps1"

    strCommand = "Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -File """ & scriptlocation & """"
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Exec (strCommand)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strCommand = "Powershell -File" & scriptlocation
```

should be

```
strCommand = "Powershell -File """ & scriptlocation & """"
```

Use the `-noexit` flag if you want to keep the window open so you can see what's going on.

Comment: I made those changes and am still having the same issue.  Editing main post now

Comment: Nevermind, the issue was that ExecutionPolicy Bypass was not set.  The line that fixed it was

strCommand = "Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -File """ & scriptlocation & """"

Yours was the almost answer lol

Answer (score 1):

Execution Policy is not set so the script won't run in default ExecutionPolicy settings command should be:

```
strCommand = "powershell -ep Bypass -F " & scriptlocation
```